# Multiclass SVM failed to use 20 News Group Dataset

Tags: python, svm, multiclass-classification

I'm trying to use multiclass SVM code from [Mblondel Multiclass SVM](https://gist.github.com/mblondel/97cffbea574a5890f0d7), I read his paper and he used dataset from sklearn 20newsgroup, but when I tried to use that, the code isn't working properly.

I tried to change the code to match 20newsgroup dataset. but I'm stuck at this error..

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "F:\env\chatbotstripped\CSSVM.py", line 157, in
>
> clf.fit(X, y)
>
> File "F:\env\chatbotstripped\CSSVM.py", line 106, in fit
>
> v = self._violation(g, y, i)
>
> File "F:\env\chatbotstripped\CSSVM.py", line 50, in _violation
>
> elif k != y[i] and self.dual_coef_[k, i] >= 0:
>
> IndexError: index 20 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 20

this is the main code:

```
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_20newsgroups
news_train = fetch_20newsgroups(subset='train')
X, y = news_train.data[:100], news_train.target[:100]

clf = MulticlassSVM(C=0.1, tol=0.01, max_iter=100, random_state=0, verbose=1)
X = TfidfVectorizer().fit_transform(X)
clf.fit(X, y)
print(clf.score(X, y))
```

this is the fit code:

```
def fit(self, X, y):
    n_samples, n_features = X.shape

    self._label_encoder = LabelEncoder()
    y = self._label_encoder.fit_transform(y)

    n_classes = len(self._label_encoder.classes_)
    self.dual_coef_ = np.zeros((n_classes, n_samples), dtype=np.float64)
    self.coef_ = np.zeros((n_classes, n_features))

    norms = np.sqrt(np.sum(X.power(2), axis=1)) # i changed this code

    rs = check_random_state(self.random_state)
    ind = np.arange(n_samples)
    rs.shuffle(ind)

    # i added this sparse
    sparse = sp.isspmatrix(X)
    if sparse:
        X = np.asarray(X.data, dtype=np.float64, order='C')

    for it in range(self.max_iter):
        violation_sum = 0
        for ii in range(n_samples):
            i = ind[ii]
        
            if norms[i] == 0:
                continue
        
            g = self._partial_gradient(X, y, i)
            v = self._violation(g, y, i)
            violation_sum += v
         
            if v < 1e-12:
                continue

            delta = self._solve_subproblem(g, y, norms, i)
            self.coef_ += (delta * X[i][:, np.newaxis]).T
            self.dual_coef_[:, i] += delta

        if it == 0:
            violation_init = violation_sum

        vratio = violation_sum / violation_init

        if self.verbose >= 1:
            print("iter", it + 1, "violation", vratio)

        if vratio < self.tol:
            if self.verbose >= 1:
                print("Converged")
            break
    return self
```

and _violation code:

```
def _violation(self, g, y, i):
    smallest = np.inf
    for k in range(g.shape[0]):
        if k == y[i] and self.dual_coef_[k, i] >= self.C:
            continue
        elif k != y[i] and self.dual_coef_[k, i] >= 0:
            continue

        smallest = min(smallest, g[k].all()) # and i added .all()
    return g.max() - smallest
```

I know there's something wrong with the index, I'm not sure how to fix that, and I don't want to ruin the code because I don't really understand how's this code works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to convert the sparse matrix output of tfidf vectorizer into dense matrix then make it as a 2D array. Try this!

```
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_20newsgroups
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
news_train = fetch_20newsgroups(subset='train')
text, y = news_train.data[:1000], news_train.target[:1000]

clf = MulticlassSVM(C=0.1, tol=0.01, max_iter=100, random_state=0, verbose=1)
vectorizer= TfidfVectorizer(min_df=20,stop_words='english')
X = np.asarray(vectorizer.fit_transform(text).todense())
clf.fit(X, y)
print(clf.score(X, y))
```

Output:

```
iter 1 violation 1.0
iter 2 violation 0.07075102408683964
iter 3 violation 0.018288133735158228
iter 4 violation 0.009149083942255389
Converged
0.953
```

Comment: thanks it works! next, i want to try to predict using my own sentences, the steps are.. 1. preprocessing the input text, 2. transform input text to tfidf 3. predict and get the category as number right? and should i use inverse label encoder to get the category name?

Comment: yes, you would only get the category as a number. You have to use decoding to get your category name